# How to use antd divider to separate two sides of the screen in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antd and would like the vertical divider to split the two sides of my screen. The two sides are in fact separated by different `Col` components. They currently look something like this:

```
 class Example extends React.Component {
   render () {
     return (
      <Row>
        <Col span={11}>
          CONTENT ONE SIDE
        </Col>
        <Col span={2}>
          <Divider type='vertical'/>
        </Col>
        <Col span={11}>
          CONTENT OTHER SIDE
        </Col>
      </Row>
     )
   }
 }
```

The issue here is that the Divider is barely appearing. I would like it to go all the way down where the content ends. Instead, it is just a tiny little line.

This is a screenshot of what it currently looks like:

[image]

You can barely see the divider in the middle.

How can I make the vertical divider be as long as the content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `height` of the divider to `100%` , see [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-create-react-app-0ib94?fontsize=14)

```
    <Divider type="vertical" style={{ height: "100%" }} />
```

Comment: Although this does work, I am not going to be able to know the height of its `Col` parent component, so as it stands this won't work.

Comment: This is the correct answer... You don't need to know the `Col` height

Answer (score 1):

if height's 100 **%** doesn't work, add `<Row>`. I predict you use only `<Col />`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mine doesn't work with the above answers.
After a little bit of work. I finally got this below code to work.

```
< Divider
   type="vertical"      style={{ height: "100px", backgroundColor: "#000" }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

height 100%

```
    <Row>
      <Col span={11}>
        CONTENT ONE SIDE
        <br />
        CONTENT ONE SIDE
        <br />
        CONTENT ONE SIDE
        <br />
      </Col>
      <Col span={2}>
        <Divider type="vertical" style={{ height: "100%" }} />
      </Col>
      <Col span={11}>CONTENT OTHER SIDE</Col>
    </Row>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-create-react-app-forked-rzp10?file=/index.js:181-499

Answer (score 0):

I did it with height: auto.

```
<Divider type="vertical" style={{ height: "auto"}} />
```